# Remove anchor, but not arguments, via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to change the following example URL

```
http://www.mydomain.net/site?argument1=test1&argument2=test2#anchor
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain.net/site?argument1=test1&argument2=test2
```

with JavaScript. How would I best do that?

EDIT: With 'anchor' and the other text elements, I meant generic elements. So the anchor could also be another text. Sorry.

Comment: The first URL is broken, the anchor has to go at the **end** (after the query string)

Comment: @David Dorward: Oh, I didn't notice that, thanks. That already helps quite a bit with the problem...

Comment: @David Dorward: The URL is perfectly fine (it was `http://www.mydomain.net/site#anchor?argument1=test1&argument2=test2`) This form could be used to create a history for Ajax requests, including parameters. The "query string" is part of the hash.

Comment: Given the context of the question, it was much more likely to be broken then an instance of the hash bang problem.

Comment: @David Dorward: Actually it made sense to me. Because the OP said he wants to reload to a **new** location. Just removing the hash and reloading will not bring him to a new location. But whatever...

Comment: it'll not bring him to a new location

Comment: @pyvi: You should know *what* URL you actually have and what you really want to do. You say you want to remove the hash and reload the page. Why?

Comment: @pyvi are you ding anything with the url like storing it for some purpose on the server side or something?

Comment: Mostly I just want to remove the hash. This will only be triggered under very specific circumstances in which the anchor the page was originall loaded with isn't on the page anymore and I want to clean up the URL so it doesn't point to a non-existant anchor. I don't care whether the page reloads or not, I just thought it had to.

Comment: @pyvi so just use javascript remove anchor and then do a location.reload. i don't think window.location.hash would do that

Comment: @pyvi: So you actually don't want to reload the page. You just want to remove the hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to change the *current* location's anchor, it's better to change `window.location.hash`:

```
window.location.hash = '';
```

In some browsers this will avoid a reload of the page as the URL changes.

Comment: That will lead to the '#' still being there. Also, I think it deletes all arguments as well.

Comment: "Also, I think it deletes all arguments as well." As I was informed, the anchor needs to go to the end anyway, so that isn't a problem. I guess then all that's left is replacing the "#"

Comment: It won't delete the arguments in a properly formatted URL (where the arguments come before the hash); if there are arguments after the hash, they're not really arguments and just part of the hash.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get rid of the remaining `#`. You could concoct a new URL out of the bits you want to keep, but note that it will cause most browsers to reload the page: `window.location = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + window.location.search`

Comment: You could also use the [`window.history` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) to replace the URL without reloading the page, but that's starting to get really complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.location = window.location.replace(/#anchor/,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I tried this, and it worked perfectly fine:

```
var url=window.location.toString(); 
url=url.replace(/#anchor/,''); 
window.location=url;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should replace #anchor but also #anchor_etc or #anchor-etc from your url
`var url =  "http://www.mydomain.net/site?argument1=test1&argument2=test2#anchor";`
`url = url.replace(/\#[a-z\-\_]+/i, '');`

Answer (score -1):

```
window.location = window.location.replace('#anchor','');
```